# How to render a video with vp9 webm codec?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

How can I render a video using FFmpeg or any other tool to get a video with google's vp9 webm codec?

The closest I have got was using openShot to get a vp8 webm video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest method using FFmpeg is to use something like the following:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0 \
       -c:a libopus -b:a 96k \
       output.webm
```

This will output [Constant Quality](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9#constantq) video and is a great choice if you are not fussed about file size. The recommended `-crf` setting is between 15-31 with lower numbers meaning better quality.

Much more detail is available on the FFmpeg trac site:

- [FFmpeg and VP9 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9)

Answer (score 0):

The `vpx-tools` package includes VP8 and VP9 encoding/decoding tools.